# Firebase and Swift 3

Tags: firebase, swift3

I have searched around and have not found the particular answer that I am seeking for. I just went and updated my App to a Swift 3 Language from swift 2. It obviously threw out a host of errors which I went through and fixed to the best of my abilities and now I do not have any errors. I can run the app but I cant tell if anything else is working because the Login or Auth sections of the app are not working. I know that I can just bypass to test but I have been working on it a lot and trying to get this feature to work that worked well before the language was changed..

Very simple my question is this:
I upgraded to Swift 3. Do I need to upgrade the cocoa pods to support the change in language? If not is it just an issue with the way that my code is and because of the change to swift 3 that i need to keep tinkering with?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

sorry posted that about 12 hours to early. After doing a lot of research it looks like I found the answer. have not tested yet but I think I am getting the same errors in the compiler.

**"We've noticed what seems to be an issue with the latest iOS 10 simulators (up to beta 6 at the time of this writing) that causes Firebase Auth to throw an error due it to not being able to write values to the keychain. This issue does not affect real devices." This is from a Firebase Blog**

Comment: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/ios-10-xcode-8-and-swift-3.html

Answer (score 0):

Hello I got this problem on the device and not on simulator, my device is iOS 9.3.3 and the strange thing is that when run from xcode it works just fine

But when I open from device after stopping debug from xcode, the error will occur

And after some digging, I found out that if pod is only using firebase, it connect just fine even opening from the device

But if I add just 1 pod, it will error like above, so I don't really understand what is going on

And yes already try using keychain sharing

Any tips?

Edit: it works fine on other devices running iOS 8.1